# Is python interpreted or compiled into byte code and interpreted when i type single line command in cmd?

Tags: python, python-3.x, compilation, interpreter

i know that a python script file is compiled into '.py' byte code and then the '.py' file is interpreted. But, when i type just a single line into cmd like

```
 >>>python    -line (0)
 >>>i=5       -line (1)
 >>>print(i)  -line (2)
 5            -line (3)
```

does it **Case 1:** compile it and then interpret it.  **case 2:** interpret it directly from high level language. I am newbie to python and have  been searching for this answers for hours please do answer it.

Comment: Which python implementation are we discussing?

Comment: Im a newbie to python and im using python 3.7.0 using cmd in my windows 10 OS and i dont know if im using a cpython or pypy or anything else.....this is the first time im hearing about "python implementation".

Comment: While it is interesting, this is not really an SO kind of question. Your questions might be more directly answered in one of the python.org lists https://www.python.org/community/lists/ or one of the SIGs (Special Interest Group) https://www.python.org/community/sigs/

Comment: @lit seems on-topic to me, as long as the question is boiled down to "does $implementation of python compile to bytecode on interactive interpreter".  A solid answer will explain "yes", show how the interactive interpreter works, and explain how the python internal VM works (state machine over bytecode)

Comment: @AnthonySottile - Ok, that's fine if you want to run it this way. You might want to take the `cmd` tag off since it is not actually involved in this process. The user types into the interactive Python executable and not the `cmd` shell.